# How can I use asp.net forms authentication to authenticate a Google/OpenSocial Gadget

Tags: asp.net, authentication, google-gadget, opensocial

I have a web site that uses Asp.net forms authentication to login. I need to enable users to login and interact with the site via gadgets using the same authetnication/authorization schema I use on the site.

I could not find any good information regarding asp.net authentication and google gadgets.

How can I make the gadgets login using the forms authentication and then have the gadget remember them so they don't have to login every time?

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach you could take is to have a checkbox in your login for "remember this logon" or something similar, and then using cookies to preserve your authentication state. One guide to doing this is the ff:

[How to implement forms authentication in your ASP.NET application](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301240)

The cookie, in turn, can save the login information that will be used for authenticating via the Google gadget API.

Needless to say there are security risks entailed, so be weary of those.